# Chrome compass source maps 403 (Forbidden) Error

Tags: google-chrome, source-maps, compass

I'm trying to get my compass source maps working on chrome.

So far they appear in chrome developer tools as origin, even line numbers are correct but they are not editable, when i click on them I get 403 Error and blank file.

my config.rb

```
css_dir = "skin/frontend/pr/default/css"
sass_dir = "skin/frontend/pr/default/scss"
images_dir = "skin/frontend/pr/default/images"
javascripts_dir = "skin/frontend/pr/default/js"
relative_assets = true
line_comments = true
sourcemap = true

output_style = :expanded
environment = :development
```

in chrome settings I have enabled source maps and css auto reloading.

I'm using newest chrome and OS X Yosemite v2